# C++ atomic runtime error

Tags: c++, atomic

Программа компилируеться, но выводит всегда одно и тоже число, и не выходит корректно

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

class myObject{
    public:
        void setContent(int i){
            this->cont = i;
            return;
        }
        int getContent(){
            return this->cont;
        }
    private:
        int cont;
};

void myfunc(atomic<myObject*>* ptr,bool* isNeed){
    auto target =  ptr->load();
    while (*isNeed){
        for (int i=0;i<=100;i++){
            target = ptr->load();
            target->setContent(i%3*i/i%2);
            ptr->store(target);
            //this_thread::yield();
        }
    }
    return;
}

void myfunc2(atomic<myObject*>* ptr,bool* isNeed){
    auto target =  ptr->load();
    while(*isNeed){
        target=ptr->load();
        cout << "Content is:"<<target->getContent()<<"\n";
        ptr->store(target);
    }
    return;
}

int main(){
    cout << "Testing: \n";
    atomic<myObject*>* target = new atomic<myObject*>();
    target->store(new myObject);
    bool isNeed1=true;

    thread gen(myfunc,target,&isNeed1);gen.detach();
    //gen.detach();

    thread consume(myfunc2,target,&isNeed1);consume.detach();
    //consume.detach();

    this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(100));
    isNeed1 = false;
    this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    delete target;
    cout << "Trigger set to false;\n";
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Компилятор даже warning не выдает

Comment: Простите, разбираться всерьез сейчас некогда, но замечу, что вы требуете атомарности *указателя*, а не того, на что он указывает...

Comment: Еще у вас деление на ноль, вот тут: `for (int i=0;i<=100;i++){
            target = ptr->load();
            target->setContent(i%3*i/i%2);`

Comment: Чего именно вы пытались добиться этим atomic?